# Microsoft cloud health api not returning refresh token next time

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-band

I have a web application which uses Microsoft cloud health api and everything is working fine in oauth2 cycle and I am getting access_token and refresh_token first time around but when I use the refresh token to get new access_token at that time I am not getting refresh token again. I have requested offline_access and I have similar api which links with Microsoft onedrive which is working perfect. I believe it is to with access_token I receive from Microsoft health cloud:

{"token_type":"bearer","expires_in":3600,"scope":"mshealth.ReadProfile mshealth.ReadDevices mshealth.ReadActivityHistory mshealth.ReadActivityLocation","access_token":*

Notice they have omitted "offline_access" but it was definitely sent as my web prompt asks for offline access and I also get a refresh token

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have started working after I changed my oauth registration from Live SDK application to Converged Applications. Not sure what the difference is though